# Two events depending on each other.

Tags: logic

Person A goes to a party P only if person B goes, but B also only goes if A goes.

Is this an uncertain statement or do they not go at all? I can think of two argumentations, of which the second is probably flawed:

Uncertain, because the two events depend on each other without an additional value they can depend on.

They don't go, because their initial status is not going, and because of the cross-dependency, that status doesn't change.

How can this situation be formalized?

Comment: The confusion may arise from confounding factual/historical perspective with cause-and-effect.  In a factual framework the claims amount to saying simply either both went or neither went to a party.  Statements about causality need to be framed in a way that directs an effect, as causes "precede" effects.

Answer (score 1):

Think about $A$. There are only two cases. Either $A$ goes to the party or does not. Say he does. But $A$ goes only if $B$ does so consequently so does $B$. Say $A$ does not go to the party. Then $B$ won't either by the second statement. There are only two cases.

- Both party
- Both don't